# Django-Heroku: Data in models not persistent

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models

I have deployed a web app with Heroku and developed using Django.

Problem:
Every time the app goes to sleep, and when it wakes up, objects in the Django models get reset to their original state (empty model). I am not entirely sure what is the problem I am facing here.

What I suspect:

1. db.sqlite3 file does not get updated when I make any changes.
2. App resets to original state after waking up from sleep. Procfile gets run again.

What have I tried:

1. Searching Google for any leads on what might be the problem.
2. Updating model locally before redeploying on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy you are using will not work because heroku does not persist data after an app is started [more here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku). What you want is to [provision a database such as postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) so that your data is available all the time.